# Java overided equals method

Tags: java, collections, equals

Are there any implementation of `List` `Map` or `Set` which not overridden`equals` method.

Comment: i guess none of them override equals ..

Comment: Have you looked at the API? It will answer this for you.

Comment: You cannot **overdo** the equals method... Not to mention the hashCode... (pun intended... pet peeves of mine both)

Comment: Why do you want to do this???

Answer (score 2):

No.

The `List`, `Map` and `Set` APIs all specify a behaviour for `equals` that can only be implemented by overriding the `java.lang.Object.equals(Object)` method.  And that's what they do.

If you want a collection class that breaks the API contract for `equals` you will need to implement it yourself; e.g. by `extend`ing an existing collection class and (re-)overriding the `equals(Object)` and `hashcode()` methods so that they behave like the original `Object` versions.